# Blender is allowed, but Prusa Slicer not?

Tags: permissions, directory, blender

I encountered a problem I don't understand. After I installed Prusa Slicer on my pc I am unable to reach the "media" folder within this program. If the data is in the folder "downloads" or "documents" on my main drive, everything is fine. But anything on my second drive is unable to reach.
BUT
If I open e. g. Blender and try to reach the same destination that is not allowed for Prusa, everything works and I can manage files in this directory.

So... my question is, what did I get wrong here?

Comment: Is Prusa Slicer a 'snap' type program?

Comment: Good point @OrganicMarble and `snap search prusa` indeed turns up a snap package, whereas `apt policy prusa` doesn't turn up anything.

Comment: You mean, did I installed it from the snap-store?

I used "Discover" for installation

Comment: Thanks guys! You are absolute right. At a second glace, I saw I installed it indeed with snap. It's also mentioned in Discover with the little symbol. 
So... I went to snap, searched for prusa and changed the permissions, which are very straight forward descripted.
So... Problem solved! Thanks!